# How to offset a background image in MS PowerPoint with VBA?

Tags: vba, powerpoint, powerpoint-2016

I need to offset the background image in MS PowerPoint using VBA. I am able to add the background image but not sure how to offset it. Hence, need a little help here:

[image]

Here's my VBA code to add a background image:

```
With ActivePresentation.Slides(1)
    
    .FollowMasterBackground = False
    
    .Background.Fill.UserPicture ("C:\Users\<user>\Pictures\Camera Roll\bg.jpg")

End With
```

*I use the MSO 2016 version.

Much thanks!

Comment: Try adding:   .Background.Fill.TextureOffsetX = 25  ' Value in Points (you can also adjust TextureOffsetY and a few other properties)

Comment: @SteveRindsberg This works for texture but not for a UserPicture.

Comment: Good point. It seems to work if you first set .Background.Fill.UserPicture (your picture file) then .Background.Fill.TextureTile = True